# Choosing the best checkpoint of a model

Tags: deep-learning, classification, image-classification

As of now, the best way of choosing the "ideal" checkpoint is to select a certain KPI and based on that KPI selecting the checkpoint of the model.

But as I go over the train/evaluation plots I see that the KPI I'm interested in is fluctuating a lot (which is a different story).
Now if that the case, there might be a checkpoint that will have best KPI over the validation although it might be a bit misleading and in some cases it does not gives the best result on the test-set.

Some details:

1. During the training I save a checkpoint every ~1000 iterations
2. My KPI is class-balanced accuracy
3. My main task is classification
4. module used - PyTorch

I would appreciate if one can refer me to best practices to how is best to select checkpoint.

Comment: Every N training iterations (or after every epoch), you evaluate your model on the **validation data** with respect to whatever metric you deem important (e.g. your KPI, or the loss function) and, if the resulting validation is better than the previous best model, you write it to disk. The key is evaluating on data you are not training on, which should be a good proxy of unseen data in the wild.

Comment: @noe thanks! I agree but I was wondering if there is any other methodological way of choosing that checkpoint from multiple ones when the validation KPI graph is really noisy (and although there might be a peak it might not be the optimal on the holdout-set)